# How to make it so that when someone receives or loses a role it sends a specific message in a set channel

Tags: discord.py, pycord

I'm trying to have the bot send a message every time someone loses or receives the Dark Role. I'm somewhat new to discord.py but still, know quite a few things.

This is my code:

```
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    role = discord.utils.get(before.guild.roles, name='Dark Clan')
    channel = discord.utils.get(before.guild.channels, name='-dark-clan')
    if role in after.roles:
        await channel.send(f"Welcome to the Dark Clan {before.mention}")
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    rolel = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name='Dark Clan')
    channell = discord.utils.get(after.guild.channels, name='-dark-clan')
    if rolel not in after.roles:
      await channell.send(f"{after.mention} left the clan."))
```